# How to set javascript break point in browser from Emacs?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, emacs, automation

As a JS developer, I want to press a key on a line in a JS file and have a debug breakpoint set on it in the browser's debugger.  For bonus points, the way to find this line should be "fuzzy" because my build system may prepend other JS in front of the current file.

I'm aware of slime-js, which talks to in-page JS, but I'm looking for a connection to Firebug or Chrome "Developer Tools".

Comment: How should it determine which browser tab/instance to talk to? I would think you would need a specific tab tied to Emacs at the point at which you wished to manipulate it?

Answer (score 1):

That's what I have in my .emacs

```
(defun line-matches-p (regexp)
  (string-match-p
   regexp
   (buffer-substring
    (line-beginning-position)
    (line-end-position))))

(defun js-toggle-debugger ()
  (interactive)
  (if (line-matches-p "debugger")
      (delete-region (line-beginning-position)
                     (1+ (line-end-position)))
      (progn (beginning-of-line)
             (insert "\n")
             (backward-char)
             (insert "debugger;")
             (indent-according-to-mode)
             (end-of-line))))
```

It inserts or deletes the "debugger" keyword. I've used it with firebug and moz-repl.

The downside is that it requires you to re-evaluate the function.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  But when the browser debugger is very good at managing breakpoints now-a-days, which is why I want to defer this to the browser.  I'm also trying to avoid page reloads.